# Confused about the 'this' keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I haven't used Javascript in a long time and have been refreshing myself on it today. One thing that always got me was the `this` keyword. I know in jQuery event handlers, such as the click event, `this` refers to the element that fired the event. How is `this` passed to the function that I give it as a callback even though my function has no arguments?

Given the following code:

```
$("tr.SummaryTbRow").data("Animating", false);
$("tr.SummaryTbAltRow").data("Animating", false);

$("tr.SummaryTbRow").click(function () {
    if ($(this).data("Animating") == false) {
        if ($(this).next(".Graph").css("display") == "none") {
            $(this).data("Animating", true);

            //Part I am questioning.
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(this).data("Animating", false);
            }(this), 550);

            $(this).next(".Graph").slideRow('down', 500);
        }
        else {
            $(this).data("Animating", true);
            $(this).next(".Graph").slideRow('up', 500);
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to figure out how to pass the element table row with class `SummaryTbRow` to my setTimeout call back function. Does jQuery pass `this` in a similar fasion to what I am doing with my anonymous call back function? Does my `this` inside the function refer to the `this` I pass in?

I know I could just do:

```
setTimeout(function (element) {
    $(element).data("Animating", false);
}(this), 550);
```

But I want to figure out how jQuery is able to pass `this` to my call back function even though my function takes 0 arguments.

Comment: jQuery uses `.call/.apply` to invoke callback function which lets you maintain the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

You can set `this` on a function by using the function's `.call()` and `.apply()` methods.

Long answer:

The `this` variable on any function is similar to the `arguments` variable (which is probably something you didn't know about). It's set when the function is called and is an artifact of how the function is called. To explain, let me start with a demonstration of `arguments`. Consider:

```
myFunction = function () {
    return arguments.length;
};
```

Now let's look at a couple calls to `myFunction`:

```
myFunction(); //is 0
myFunction(null); //is 1
myFunction(undefined); //is 1
myFunction(0, 0, 0, 0, 0); //is 5
```

As you can see, the value of `arguments.length` is not dependent on how or where we wrote the function, but on how we *called* the function. The same is true of the `this` variable (otherwise known as the "calling object"). There are exactly 3 methods for setting the calling object (there's a sort-of 4th in ES5, but we'll ignore that):

1. You can set it by calling the function using dot-notation (e.g. `something.myFunction()`)
2. You can set it by using the function's `.call()` or `.apply()` methods (e.g. `myFunction.call(someObject)`)
3. If it's not set using method #1 or #2, it will default to the global object (e.g. `window`)

So most people are used to method #1. If you assign your function as a property of an object, then call the function using the object and dot-notation, then the object gets set as `this`. Like so:

```
var myFn = (function () { return this.x });

var myObj = {
    x: 1,
    y: myFn
};

myObj.myFn(); //is 1
```

But we can also use method 2 if `myFn` isn't a property of the object we want to call it on but the object follows the correct form for `myFn` to be able to act on it (see: duck typing):

```
var myOtherObj = {
    x: 2
}

myFn.call(myOtherObj); //is 2
myFn.apply(myOtherObj); //is 2
myFn.apply({ x : 3}); //is 3
```

Pretty cool, eh? This is how jQuery does it. When they execute your callback, they do so using `.apply(event.target)` (setting `this` to the event's target object). They do it in a more complex manner because of their `callbacks` framework, [but the idea is there](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/callbacks.js#L68).

Anyway, I wouldn't be offering a long answer if I didn't toss in an explanation of method #3, which drives some people totally insane: What happens if you don't set the calling object?

Because all global variables are implicit properties of the global object, you get some interesting effects from method #3. Such as:

```
var x = 4;
myFn(); //is 4
```

But most of the time you're not lucky enough to have your global object meet the requirements the function has for its calling object, so usually it just results in an error and a lot of frustration.

Probably more than you were looking for, but hopefully you're now much more informed on the calling object and its wily ways.

Comment: Darn, accepted another answer. That's what I get for taking 15 minutes to offer a thorough answer that cites sources and offers a complete explanation. Oh well.

Comment: I waited a while for you pete. I wasn't sure if you were still going at it. You definitely went into more detail on how exactly jQuery does it and more info on this.

Answer (score 3):

To answer you last question, you may pass the receiver of your choice to a function in  javascript using for exemple [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) :

```
someFunction.call(someObject);
```

Inside `someFunction`, `this` will be `someObject`.

In your case, what you seem to want is

```
setTimeout(function (element) {
    $(element).data("Animating", false);
}, 550, this); // this will be passed as element to the callback
```

or ([more compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout))

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    $(_this).data("Animating", false);
}, 550);
```

Comment: I see, that cleared things up. I didn't realize call existed. I will have to make use of that.

Comment: You rarely have to use *call* or *bind* directly. For most standard use of jQuery, you may simply embed your variable in a closure (my last example).

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function using [`fn.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`fn.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) both of which take a context argument which is used for `this`.

Answer (score 0):

[Apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)  and [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) methods serve for that purpose. In your case you just write:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(this).data("Animating", false);
}.bind(this), 550);
```