# confusion about the 'this' keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I can claim that 'this' keyword is the most confusing part of Javascript for those who comes from languages like C#.

I have read a lot about this on the internet and on StackOverflow too. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847059/i-am-confused-about-the-keyword-this-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608807/confused-about-the-this-keyword-in-javascript).

I know that 'this' keyword will be bound to the context. and in constructor function it will be bound to the object being created, and when there is no immediate context it will bound to global object (i.e window)

I know all that , however confusion is still not fully cleared; So the best way to understand is by testing codes.

---

So I decided to write small code and I was surprised by how much convoluted the `this` keyword.

here is the code i tested:

```
 function sayHi(name){
   var tt = name;
   return {
     ss: tt,
     work: function(anotherName){

     alert ("hiiiii    " + anotherName);
   }
 };
}

//this method invocation has no effect at all right now
sayHi("John");


var hi2 = new sayHi("wallace");

hi2.work("May");
alert(hi2.ss);
```

as expected the alert window will show (Hiiiiii May ) then ( wallace). Notice now that the line `sayHi("John");` has no effect at all.

and Now the confusion will start when I change one thing ONLY (change var tt => this.tt):

```
 function sayHi(name){
   //this is the ONLY change I did.
   this.tt = name;
   return {
     ss: tt,
     work: function(anotherName){

     alert ("hiiiii    " + anotherName);
   }
 };
}

// Now this line invocation will be problematic 
sayHi("John");


var hi2 = new sayHi("wallace");

hi2.work("May");
alert(hi2.ss);
```

the result surprised me when the alert mthod gave ( Hiiiiiii May ) and then (John) not (wallace);

so I had the idea to comment the line `sayHi("John");` but that resulted in the whole code being no-functional and not working.

the [demo is here](http://jsbin.com/vuxabeju/1/edit)

I know this might be newbee question. But it is really confusing here and I did try to read many articles and SO questions but i m missing this point.

Why does the line `sayHi("John");` setting the hi2.ss to John?? and why does it break the code when we delete it ; although we invoke the `sayHi` method by using the `new` keyword afterward ??

Comment: In "strict" mode, `this` is `undefined` when a function is invoked without any context.

Comment: `ss: tt,` is assigning based on a local var, not a property of this, since the var doesn't exist it should be undefined.

Comment: @scragar after reading the answers down and understand all of them . now your comment make sense . thanks man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first invoke `sayHi("John");`, `this` will point to the global object `window`. That means `this.tt = name` actually creates a global `tt` variable.

Then when you invoke `new sayHi("wallace");`, `this` correctly points to a new instance of `sayHi`, but you are returning another object instead of letting `new` naturally return the instance.

If you carefully look at your object literal, you define `ss` like `ss: tt,`. Since you aren't using `this.tt` and there is no `tt` symbol found in the constructor's scope, the value will then be resolved as a global variable (which was previously set to `John`).

Comment: I love you man .. although all answers here are informative; however you alerted me about the object literal mistake I did. when I define the `ss:tt` to `ss:this.tt` the behavior of the code is as expected ... now I figured it out.

Comment: am I allowed to edit your answer so I add the code in its correct format?

Comment: @stackunderflow I'm glad I could help. Instance variables attached to `this` and function-scoped variables declared with `var` are two very distinct things. Accessing a variable on it's own e.g. `someVar` rather than `this.someVar` or `obj.someVar` will never resolve to an object member (except global variables wich are properties of `window` in a browser).

Comment: @stackunderflow Usually it's not an accepted practice to modify the content of an answer, unless you are not changing it's meaning. This usually means that you cannot do much more than fixing grammar mistakes or typos. The answer's creator is not the only one involved in the editing approval process and your edit might very well be rejected by people that are foreing to this conversation. It's usually best to leave a comment and let the answer's owner deal with it.

Answer (score 6):

Because you assign the parameter "name" to a property of the object referenced by `this` (which in this case will be `window`), your subsequent reference to "tt" in that object literal will be to the "tt" property of the global object, since that's the next enclosing scope.

Your first call to "sayHi" is made without the `new` operator, so in that call `this` will refer to the global object (`window`). The first line in the second version

```
this.tt = name;
```

therefore will set `window.tt` to "John".

The next call is made with the `new` operator. Because of that, `this` in the function refers to the newly-instantiated object. The line

```
this.tt = name;
```

will therefore really have no net effect on anything, because the function returns a *different* object in all cases. The last line of your test:

```
alert(hi2.ss);
```

says "John" because that's what's in `window.tt`.  Why does that matter? Because "sayHi" returns an object with a property ("ss") set from the value of the symbol "tt". The only "tt" in scope will be `window.tt`, which was set back in the *first* call to the function.

Comment: thank for you answer .. but still im confused. so you say that when I invoke sayHi("john") the 'this' is (window) and then it is window.tt = john... but why when I invoke the method again with new object created (hi2) the hi2.tt is still john not wallace?? im confused still.. appreciating further illustration

Comment: It's "John" because in the second call, `this` is **not** `window` - you call it with `new`.

Comment: great clarification. appreciating your patience , but now my question is as follow : first call sayHi("john") gave me a variable (window.tt = "john"); but the second call (hi2 = new sayHi("wallace") should give me another variable ( hi2.tt = "wallace") .. are you saying that tt is not allowed locally since it is set up globally??

Comment: No, it's not `hi2.tt` - it's the brand new object that's created due to your calling the function via `new`.  The first line of the function will succeed in setting that object's "tt" property to "wallace", but then you set "ss" to just plain "tt" and not "this.tt".

Answer (score 3):

When invoking a constructor function, if no return statement exists in the function then `this` is implicitly returned otherwise the return value is returned and `this` is simply ignored.

In your second example you are saving the name argument as `this.tt` but returning a different object. That's why things aren't working. Basically use `this` or return a custom object, but don't do both.

Comment: That's not really the issue. I think the OP is well-aware that he's overriding the implicit return. The OP's confusion is more about why `ss: tt` doesn't result in his expectations.

Comment: @plalx: My answer _does_ explain why `ss: tt` doesn't result in his expectations.